# Получаю null при вызове массива пользовательского типа, объявленного в классе C#

Tags: c#

Хочу создать тип данных, на основании его создать массив и потом в него закинуть данные, так вот:

1. Объявляю свой тип:

   ```cs
   public class TIntelHexData {
       public byte type;
       public ushort halfAddress;
       public byte[] data = new byte[16];
   }
   ```
2. Создаю класс, где на основании созданного типа создаю массив, изначально не выделял память под него.

   ```cs
   public class IntelHexHandler
   {
       private TIntelHexData[] dataSendBuff = new TIntelHexData[2000];//buffer 
       private byte typeOfMessageHex; //тип строки intel hex
       private byte longOfMessageHex; //длина строки intel hex

       public void IntelHexSort(ref byte[] buff)//файл
       {
       }
       public void IntelHexSendBlock(byte size, ref SerialPort port)
       {
       }
   }
   ```
3. Создаю экземпляр класса и вызываю внутренние методы:

   ```cs
   private async void Send_to_Flash_btn_ClickAsunc(object sender, EventArgs e)//кнопка
   {
       IntelHexHandler intelHexHandler = new IntelHexHandler();
       await WaitingBeforeNextOperationAsync();//ждем флага выполнения операции
       intelHexHandler.IntelHexSort(ref dataBuffHex);
       intelHexHandler.IntelHexSendBlock(16, ref serialPort1);
   }
   ```
4. Как только происходит присваивание внутри класса в массив, получаю `NullReferenceException`, что я делаю не так? Показан кусок из метода.

   ```cs
   if (CRCcalculated == CRCget)//если чек суммы равны
   {
       dataSendBuff[counter].halfAddress = addressLSB;//ошибка null

       for (byte t = 0; t < temp_buff2.Length - 2; t++)
       {
           dataSendBuff[counter].data[t] = temp_buff2[t];
       }

       dataSendBuff[counter].type = (byte)Protocol_Id.FirmBody_DATA; 
       counter++;
       //сохраняем младший адрес и данные прошивки intel hex
   }
   else
   {
       /*Ошибка по crc*/
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё правильно, экземпляр класса кто будет создавать? Сам он магичнским образом не появится.

```
if (CRCcalculated == CRCget)
{
    dataSendBuff[counter] = new TIntelHexData();
    dataSendBuff[counter].halfAddress = addressLSB;
    // здесь надо быть внимательным. Если temp_buff2.Length - 2 будет больше 16, вы получите исключение. Потому что new byte[16]
    // в этом случае массив лучше создавать здесь, а не в классе TIntelHexData. Длина же известна
    for (byte t = 0; t < temp_buff2.Length - 2; t++)
    {
        dataSendBuff[counter].data[t] = temp_buff2[t];
    }

    dataSendBuff[counter].type = (byte)Protocol_Id.FirmBody_DATA; 
    counter++;
}
else
{
    /*Ошибка по crc*/
}
```

---

Второй вариант решения использовать не класс, а структуру, то есть значимый тип, который не может быть `null`

```
public struct TIntelHexData
{
    public byte type;
    public ushort halfAddress;
    public byte[] data;
}
```

Тогда ваш код отработает без вызова конструктора, но придется массив `data` создавать в коде, либо реализовывать полноценный конструктор структуры, где инициализируются все её поля.

```
if (CRCcalculated == CRCget)
{
    dataSendBuff[counter].halfAddress = addressLSB;
    int length = temp_buff2.Length - 2:
    dataSendBuff[counter].data = new byte[length];
    for (byte t = 0; t < length; t++)
    {
        dataSendBuff[counter].data[t] = temp_buff2[t];
    }

    dataSendBuff[counter].type = (byte)Protocol_Id.FirmBody_DATA; 
    counter++;
}
else
{
    /*Ошибка по crc*/
}
```